# How to change back vold.fstab with PC while Phone doesn't startup nor I can reset it

Tags: android

Since I changed my *sdcard* to *sdcard1* in `system/etc/vold.fstab`file, Now neither phone starts up nor I can reset. Can i reset it with PC or Change `vold.fstab` With PC. Phone is **Sony Ericsson Experia Lt18i**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to boot to recovery, if you get there, use adb to revert things, otherwise you can always come back to stock if you mess things up. Here's a link with steps and useful information. Install the PC Companion app follow the steps to do a factory reset.

http://www.hardreset.info/devices/sony-ericsson/sony-ericsson-xperia-arc-s-lt18i/

Answer (score 0):

This method works perfectly in my Micromax A77 phone which I have rooted and have used the modified vold.fstab file for swapping the phone memory with the external card memory. Basically what happened in older smartphones (like 2015/2014 and before ones) that the manufacturers offered only limited amount of internal memory, like 2 GB or 4 GB max. So the internal memory became full even after installing a few apps and games as not all the memory was accessible. The android system also ate up almost 1/3rd of the available internal memory right from the day the phone was used. That made the users high and dry as the phone became really useless since one could not install any apps or games from play store or even from any apk file. Even the update of most of the apps failed from play store due to insufficient space problem. There are a number of third party apps link Link2SD etc but most of them don't work properly to help the users. Basically the main thing any user want is increase in phone memory/internal memory but that is not possible as that has already been installed by the manufacturer in the phone so u cannot install extra memory in the phone memory or internal memory. What u can do at most is insert an external Sd Card of 4/8/16/32/64 GB.... or any capacity that you device supports. But this also fails the purpose as the new apps will still be installed on the internal/phone memory and the not the external sd card thus defeating the purpose of increasing memory using external sd card. So there is no other option but to increase the phone memory which is possible using the tweaking and editing of the vold.fstab file. This file, the vold.fstab file is a system file which is present inside the "etc" folder of root folder (/). One needs total root access and a file explorer like ES explorer to access and edit the file. Using ordinary file explorer such as that provided by the manufacturer will not work in this case as the root folder and associated folders can only be accessed only using special explorers and ES Explorer is certainly one of the best explorers out there in the market. But to use the full functionality (to edit the vold.fstab) file, one needs to have root permissions which means that the phone should be rooted beforehand otherwise the process won't work. So this method only works for phone that are are rooted.

Once u have installed ES File explorer and assuming that u have granted Super User (SU) permissions to the ES explorer (when prompted by the SU), please navigate to the root of the phone (/). Go to the etc folder and open that folder. In side the etc folder u will find the vold.fstab file. Now long press the file. It will get selected and then u need to touch the more option on the explorer app. Once u press on more, u will get several options..select properties. Now select permissions on the properties option by touching on change. Select Read, Write and Execute options for both group and owner. Press Ok to change the permissions so that everyone has full access on this file (Read, Write and Execute). Then go back to the vold.fstab file and now open it instead of selecting it. The file will open but to edit it u will need to select the three dots on the menu and then select the Edit Option.

Once u are able to scroll the cursor over the file for editing, go to the line where it says :

"##Example of a standard sdcard mount for the emulator / Dream

## Mounts the first usable partition of the specified device

dev_mount sdcard /storage/sdcard0 emmc@fat /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 /devices/platform/mtk-msdc.0/mmc_host
dev_mount sdcard2 /storage/sdcard1 auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.1"

Now u need to come to the place in the above lines where its mentioned: "dev_mount sdcard /storage/sdcard0"

U need to change the sdcard0 to sdcard1 (This will make the system think that the phone memory is the external sd card)

Now u also need to change the other line too. U need to come to the next line where it is mentioned:
"dev_mount sdcard2 /storage/sdcard1"

U need to change the sdcard1 to sdcard0 (This will make the system think that the external memory/sd card is the phone memory).

Now u need to press the back button on the ES explorer editor. It will ask you to save the file. Press save and then reboot your phone. Now go to your phone storage and check. There will be 99% chances that the phone memory will show as sd card and your external sd card will now show as phone memory. If that is true then you have successfully tricked your phone into believing the way u wanted to be.

So basically in this process u are replacing the two numbers 0 and 1 in the vold.fstab file. The original file contains the first line as sdcard0 and the second line contains sd card1. They need to be replaced vice versa that is the sd card0 becomes sd card 1 and the sd card 1 becomes sd card 0. Simple.

To change the phone back to the original setting just replace the 0 and 1 as it was in the original file. The first line will be sdcard0 and the second line will be sdcard1. This will bring the phone to its original, factory state where the phone was actually the phone memory and the external memory was the actual ext card.

Thx for reading the post. I hope it was informative.